# Present Perfect after Past Perfect in a text

Tags: present-perfect, tense-agreement

> Yesterday, when I was using a printer, it suddenly turned off in the middle of printing.  I was surprised and pushed the power button many times, but it never turned on again. I realized that it **had broken down**. I **have used it** for about four years.

Is this use of the Present Perfect following the Past Perfect okay, since the author has used the printer for quite a long time? That is, using this Present Perfect, the author is shifting the passage from "me yesterday" to "me today".

Or should one necessariliy backshift it to

> I **had used** it for about four years.

Alternatively, can one use the Present Perfect in both sentences:

> I realized that it **has broken down**. I **have used it** for about four years.

..since the event is a recent one (yesterday) and the condition still obtains (the printer still exists and it is in a broken-down condition).

Comment: You will also find the pages [here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shift from Past Perfect back to Present Perfect is fine, in an (informal) narrative context (e.g. speaking with tech support). But I might say *I've been using it for about four years* to express the fact that it was operational during that entire time.

P.S. To stay in the Past Perfect (I had used it for about four years, I had been using it....) would keep the narrative time in the past. You would be "looking back".  Tech support might get the notion that you and that printer had had a ... special relationship.

Comment: Thanks, TRomano! But "I have used it" won't look strange when compared with "I have been using it"?

Comment: In order to break this feeling of "special relationship", might one employ the Progressive? "I had been using it for about four years"?

Comment: "strange", no. It would be ok.  It's the remaining in PastPerfect that makes the story seem a little too nostalgic, not the lack of the progressive.

Comment: Just wondering if it was possible to use past simple "I used for four years" ?